# nvd3.js How to make a historical multiBarChart?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

I have multiple, labeled sets of data with dates on the x-axis and integers on the y-axis that I am stacking using nvd3.js's multiBarChart.

Because the x-axis data is sparse (there is a fixed interval between dates, but not all dates have data), the x-axis puts each stacked bar side-by-side instead of preserving the relative distance in time/date between the data points on the x-axis.

I would like to have the x-axis preserve its time/date spacing like the historicalBarChart. Is a historical multiBarChart possible with nvd3.js?

If so, how do I configure it (I've tried various x-axis settings)? If not, is my best option to use separate historicalBarCharts, one for set set of data or is there another way to achieve this?

Comment: It sounds like you're not using a time scale/axis for the x axis. Could you post your code please?

Comment: My code is data-driven so I'll try to list the steps for this specific case.

Comment: data = [
  {key: 'Bar1', values: [{x: a_date, y: a_value}, ..]}
  {key: 'Bar2', values: [{x: another_date, y: another_value}, ..]}
];

chart = nv.models.multiBarChart()
  .stacked(true);

d3.select(element).datum(data).call(chart);

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try setting the y value for each of these x values to `0` or `null` or `undefined`.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, it didn't work (I had already tried that) since it is only for displaying the tick marks (it forces a text display entry for every tick mark), not spacing the axis.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing, but it is really slow and inefficient to alter the display by adding values. I'd really like to find a way to make it act like historicalBarChart (not needing to add points).